# The HAL Browser got empty titles

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I built my background project with Spring datajpa and datarest, but when I open the browser to check my data I find that the resources got an empty title, empty name/index and no docs. How can I fill this info to make my datarest webpage beautiful?

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: I am using springframe to offer add/del/merge etc. for my app. And I can check my interfaces on the local html called The HAL Browser(for Spring Data REST) offered by spring. But on this page, I want to write some tips on my interfaces for my partner to see. Luckily I notice that 'Links' on this page has attr. like title, name, docs etc. But how could I fill these attrs in my code?